# Do forms automatically use translation in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm working on upgrading an app from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4.

I noticed some errors in the profiler in the new version on one of my routes that has a form. The errors were in Translation -> Translation Messages -> Missing:

> These messages are not available for the given locale and cannot be found in the fallback locales. Add them to the translation catalogue to avoid Symfony outputting untranslated contents.

Every form field was listed under missing messages.

I hadn't done anything with translation in the old version, so I was wondering why the new version was expecting translations. Is that something that's automatically associated with forms now? If so, is there a way to turn that off? It really isn't necessary for this app.

Comment: Which version of Symfony 3 were you using ?

Comment: @FabienPapet 3.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enable the translations in the framework bundle Forms will try to use them via the `TranslationExtension` that is automatically registered. If you don't need any translations you can disable them. Be aware that validation errors on the form are returned as their translation keys and not the message then.

In Symfony 3 the setting should be in `app/config/config.yml` and in Symfony 4 directory structure they should be in either `config/packages/framework.yaml` or `config/packages/translation.yaml` under:

```
framework:
    translator: ~ # just set this to false if you don't want any translations to be used
```

Your other option is to prevent the `TranslationExtension` from being registered or [write a custom form extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) that sets the [`translation_domain` on the abstract FormType to false](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#translation-domain).

Another option is to just ignore the notices for missing translations. Since translations are cached and will always fall back to the key (in your case the actual label) it will not have any performance impact or other negative effects.

edit: Regarding your final question, I don't think this behavior changed much from Symfony 3 to 4 and you should have seen a similar behavior before. I'm guessing you just didn't notice the warning before, but it was there. That's just a guess though.

Comment: You're right, this hadn't changed between versions. I never saw the warnings previously because translator was commented out in my config.yml, as soon as I enabled it, of course I got the warnings in the old version too. Thanks for the explanation, it was quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should `disable` Translation in `Form` like follow:

```
$builder
    ......
    ......
    ->add('budget', MoneyType::class, array(
          'label_attr' => array('class' => 'control-label'),
          'attr' => array('class' => 'span11'),
          ...
          'translation_domain' => false
    ))
    ......
    ......
    ;
```